# Flex - Issues with linkbar dataprovider

Tags: apache-flex, listbox, dataprovider

I'm having some issues displaying a linkbar.

The data I need to display is in a XML file. 
However, I couldn't get the linkbar to display a xmllist (I did indeed read that you cannot set a xmlllist as a linkbar dataprovider... ). So, I'm transforming the xmllist in a array of objects.

Here is some code.

XML file:

```
<data>
 <languages>
  <language id="en">
   <label>ENGLISH</label>
   <source></source>
  </language>
  <language id="fr">
   <label>FRANCAIS</label>
   <source></source>
  </language>
  <language id="es">
   <label>ESPAÑOL</label>
   <source></source>
  </language>
  <language id="jp">
   <label>JAPANESE</label>
   <source></source>
  </language>
 </languages>
</data>
```

AS Code that transforms the xmllist in an array of objects:

```
private function init():void
{
 var list:XMLList = generalData.languages.language;
 var arr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;
 var obj:Object;
 for(var i:int = 0; i<list.length(); i++)
 {
  obj = new Object;
  obj.id = list[i].@id;
  obj.label = list[i].label;
  obj.source = list[i].source;
  arr.addItemAt(obj, arr.length);
 }    
 GlobalData.instance.languages = arr.toArray();
}
```

Linkbar code:

```
<mx:HBox horizontalAlign="right" width="100%">
 <mx:LinkBar id="language" dataProvider="{GlobalData.instance.languages}" separatorWidth="3" labelField="{label}"/>
</mx:HBox>
```

The separator is not displaying, and neither do the label.
But the array is populated (I tested it).

Thanks for any help you can provide =)

Regards,
BS_C3

---

@Decado

Here's the code for the linkbar I used:

```
<mx:LinkBar id="language" 
    dataProvider="{GlobalData.instance.languages}" 
    labelFunction="language_labelFunction"
    itemClick="language_itemClick(event)"
    styleName="GLBLinkBTN"
    separatorColor="#FFFFFF"
    separatorWidth="1"
    linkButtonStyleName="HPLanguages"
    />
```

And here's the function for the labelfunction:

```
private function language_labelFunction(item:Object):String
{
    return item.label;
}
```

Hope this helps.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue. 
I used a labelfunction in the linkbar (instead of label property). Using a label function did the trick.

But I still do not quite understand why the label property wasn't working...

Comment: I've edited my post. Tell if you need more details about it.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you're looking for. See if you can adapt it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Array id="dataProvider">
        <mx:Object id="en" label="English" />
        <mx:Object id="fr" label="French" />
        <mx:Object id="es" label="Espanol" />
        <mx:Object id="jp" label="Japanese" />
    </mx:Array> 

    <mx:LinkBar
        horizontalCenter="0"
        verticalCenter="0"
        dataProvider="{dataProvider}"
        labelField="label" />
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for your answer.
I did what you proposed but it still doesn't work >_<